# Opening a modal window on navigation change or closing a window

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

So I'm looking to have my app open a modal popup window if a user tries to navigate away from a page or close the tab/browser with unsaved data on a form.

I've had people tell me this isn't possible as angular makes asynchronous callbacks and as such once you stop the event in order to open the modal and prevent the navigation the contents of the event are lost.

Is it possible to store the contents of the event in an object?

Comment: Maybe localstorage or sessionstorage can help you rethink how to do this.

Comment: What do you mean? As in store the information on the form in local storage so it remains after navigation?  That wouldn't work as we don't mind about the user losing the form data if they decide they want to navigate away from the page rather we only want to remind them they have unsaved data before hand.